# query to store unique values in sql table.?

Tags: sql

I have some values already store in table.Before insert some value it should check value is already stored or not.if not stored then add into table otherwise value ignored.Value stored with reference to column.

Comment: what rdbms? what have you got so far?

Comment: please provide structure of table and which value to check

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is rather vague and seemingly broad, it does have a simple answer:

```
create unique index idx_table_col on table(col)
```

This will ensure that the values in `col` are unique.  If duplicate values will cause an error, unless you catch the error and do something.  You can have more than one column in the index, so combinations of column would then be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can create stored procedure and in it

```
select count(1) into varname from table_name where column_name = data

if(varname = 0)
   your insert query goes here
```